# Edit Windows 10 start menu programmatically

Tags: windows-10

To begin with, I understand that Microsoft offers no way to programatically alter the (modern) start menu - [on purpose](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141029-00/?p=43743).

Nevertheless, I'm looking for a way to *still* do it. I might use it to make a tool to sync the start menu between devices - or to automatically place often used items into thematically sorted groups (office, games, tools). The reason is that I have multiple devices, and really suck at manually managing the start menu - so I just use search or the alphabetic list most of the time.

So, does anybody know how to programatically add, remove, edit tiles? I could imagine solutions including:

- Using undocumented APIs (can you still call it an API if it is not documented?)
- Directly editing the tile database (e.g. TileDataLayer) - downside is that it seems to be a binary format, which is not known, and you'd have to restart the shell for changes to take effect.
- Hooking DLLs or poking around in memory - yikes - but not worse than what other "desktop modding" tools like WindowBlinds would do
- Using accessibility APIs, or faking mouse/keyboard input - this would most probably work, but it would be a bit spooky seeing the cursor move around, and it seems even more frail than the others.

I searched a bit, and think there is probably no solution available right now, but you can see this as a challenge to come up with a solution :-)

Comment: design your startmenu once and export the layout with DISM or pwoershell Export-StartLayout: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/itpro/windows/manage/customize-and-export-start-layout and later import it again in new boxes with Import-StartLayout cmdlet: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt188241.aspx

Answer (score -3):

As you say, there isn't a way to do this.
As an alternative, did you know that you can easily find apps to launch by pressing the windows key and then typing the name of the app you want to launch? This is how I launch anything that isn't pinned to my taskbar. The device I'm on and the order of items in a list or what's pinned where become irrelevant when working this way.